# Magento 2 - How to get dynamic checkout fields from db in a new step?

Tags: magento2

I added an admin side interface to add some questions that the admin need to ask to customer while checkout. These questions saved in a custom table.
I wanted to add a new step in checkout, and shows the questions saved by admin in a from, with an input field for each . and need to save those in Db.
How to do it?

Comment: Do you want fields which you fill in the shipping page in payment step?

Comment: no, I want a new checkout step, in which I need to show fields with label  from my custom table.
ie, I already had table in which  I stored multiple questions I want to ask to the customer. I want to show them in a extra checkout step.

Comment: Okay, let me check.